# If $A\subset (B \cup C)$ and $B\subset (C \cup A)$, then $(A\cup B )\setminus ( A \cap B)\subset C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets A, B and C, if A is a subset of B union C and B is a subset of C union A, then A union B - A interception of B is a subset of C. How can I prove this?

Formatted: if $A \subset B \cup C$ and $B \subset C \cup A$, then $(A \cup B - A \cap B) \subset C$.

Answer (score 2):

Our goal is to show that every element of $(A \cup C - A \cap B)$ is an element of $C$. Suppose $x \in (A \cup C - A \cap B)$. Noting that $(A \cup C - A \cap B) \subset A \cup C$, we see that either $x \in A$ or $x \in C$ (or both).

Case 1: $x \in C$.

> Then we are done!

Case 2: $x \in A$.

> Then $x \notin B$ since we subtracted out $A \cap B$. But since $x \in A \subset B \cup C$, we see that $x \in C$.

Comment: sorry is then (A union B) - (A interception B) is a subset of C

Comment: @michael If every element of (A union B) - (A interception B) is also in C, then yes.

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: @michael What does "subset" mean?